# Why I receive "Deprecated" warning in Groovy Eclipse IDE but not in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, groovy

I just recently started learning Groovy and I noticed, in Groovy Eclipse, the min() and max() method calls on a collection, for example a list, are always struck out as "Deprecated". The warning message suggested that I better use the "iterable" version.

What I don't understand is a list implements iterable interface, so it is already an iterable.

(BTW, I used compiler level 2.4)

The same code didn't get any warning in IntelliJ IDEA.

Question: Is that warning legitimate? If yes, then how? Or is it a problem with IDE?

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
print list.max();
```

I even changed the variable declaration like this:

```
List list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

But still receive "Deprecated" warning.

Comment: For what code? Please show the code that's being marked as deprecated. Or an example

Comment: @tim_yates I added very small code excerpt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say, it's a problem with the IDE. Take a look at this:

```
import groovy.util.GroovyCollections

GroovyCollections.methods
    .findAll { it.name == 'max' }
    .collect { 
        [
            name: it.name, 
            parameters: it.parameterTypes, 
            annotations: it.declaredAnnotations
         ]
     }.inspect()
```

The output of the code above is...

```
[
    [
        'name':'max', 
        'parameters':[interface java.util.Collection], 
        'annotations':[@java.lang.Deprecated()]
    ], 
    [
        'name':'max', 
        'parameters':[interface java.lang.Iterable], 
        'annotations':[]
    ], 
    [
        'name':'max', 
        'parameters':[class [Ljava.lang.Object;], 
        'annotations':[]
    ]
]
```

First, I should mention that [GroovyCollections](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html) is, or can be used, as a Groovy category. So it's typically not used in the way illustrated above.

A `Collection` *is an* `Iterable`. So `Collection.max()` was deprecated in favor of `Iterable.max()` in [this](https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/5b95a1b031be6da4d3a35c4af90a855e9f95cd3c#diff-18359cc871afadbd228857d9c80feeffR226) changeset. The ticket is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6053).

So it looks like Eclipse is a bit confused.